# How to add different data into a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am very very new to vba coding and I apologize if I am ignorant to some issues but the following program is something I have come up with to check the range if there is 2 empty rows in a row and if there is then it will create a list in the second row. I also added a feature to see how many list I want to create in that range. So what I need to do is to create a certain amount of list depending on the input and to place below each list after 1 empty row. I need to include way more fruits into the list but it was getting a little long and I was wondering if there is anyway I can make it shorter. Thank you in advance and sorry if I am asking a dumb question.

```
Sub CreateList()
    Dim Emptyrow As Range
    Dim NumberOfTimes As Integer

    NumberOfTimes = InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of times to create list")
    For Each Emptyrow In Sheets("Fruit").Range("A1:A100")
        If IsEmpty(Emptyrow.Value) = True Then
            If IsEmpty(Emptyrow.Offset(1, 0).Value) = True Then
                If NumberOfTimes > 0 Then
                    With Emptyrow
                        .Offset(1, 0).Value = "apple"
                        .Offset(2, 0).Value = "banana"
                        .Offset(3, 0).Value = "watermelon"
                        .Offset(4, 0).Value = "melon"
                        .Offset(5, 0).Value = "berry"
                        .Offset(6, 0).Value = "pear"
                        .Offset(7, 0).Value = "orange"
                    End With
                    NumberOfTimes = NumberOfTimes - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Emptyrow
End Sub
```

Comment: What you can do is isolate the fruit list in another sheet. And then just call to that reference. Hard coding the list will be tedious in the long run.

Comment: I see, I could do that as well. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all your fruits into an array, then just loop through them

```
Sub CreateList()
    Dim Emptyrow As Range
    Dim NumberOfTimes As Integer

    Dim Fruits As Variant
    Fruits = Array("apple", "banana", "watermelon")

    NumberOfTimes = InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of times to create list")
    For Each Emptyrow In Sheets("Fruit").Range("A1:A100")
        If IsEmpty(Emptyrow.Value) = True Then
            If IsEmpty(Emptyrow.Offset(1, 0).Value) = True Then
                If NumberOfTimes > 0 Then
                    With Emptyrow
                        Dim i As Integer
                        For i = 0 To UBound(Fruits)
                            .Offset(i + 1, 0) = Fruits(i)
                        Next i
                    End With
                    NumberOfTimes = NumberOfTimes - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Emptyrow
End Sub
```